# fetch data using react useffect and then make a next fetch according to previous fetched data

Tags: reactjs

im getting data from api as an object and then use some inforation from the response data to make the next fetch to get the new data response
here is the code
first fecth get movie object that contain the movie post url
then pass the movie url to backgroundImage in header html tag inorder to get the movie poster
the problem that url of background image is passed as null so i got nothing

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from '../axios'
import requests from '../requests'
import {posterpath} from '../requests.js'
import '../styles/banner.css'
import {Image} from 'antd'

function Banner() {

const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
   async function fetchData(){
        const request = await axios.get(requests.fetchNetflixOriginals)
        setMovie(
            request.data.results[
                Math.floor(Math.random() * request.data.results.length -1)
            ]
        )
       
   }
   fetchData();
   console.log(movie)
}, [])

return (
    
    <header className="banner"
        style={{
            backgroundImage : `url 
("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${(movie)=>movie?.backdrop_path}")`
        }}
    >

        <div className="banner-contents">
            <h1>{movie.original_title}</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
)


export default Banner
```

Comment: Why are you using a function here? `(movie)=>movie?.backdrop_path` ? And also, the default value for the movie state should be an empty object, instead of an empty array,

Comment: The ` console.log(movie)` should show the default value. Wrap it in a separate useEffect or add the log at the end of the fetchData function to see the results of the promise

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

`${(movie)=>movie?.backdrop_path}`

to

`${movie.backdrop_path}`

Comment: i have changed it but still have the same problem

Comment: im sure its about the hooks lifecycle and rendering